# How do i generate a number between 0-9 or letter between A-Z and then initialize it as a variable

Tags: java

I want to make a randomizer so it chooses a either one number between 0-9 or one letter between A-Z.

I have already tried something like this

```
Random L1 = new Random();
char a = (char)(L1.nextInt(26) + 'A');
```

and this

```
Random N1 = new Random();
int A = N1.nextInt(10);
```

but I'm curious if it is possible to combine both and still receive on output(either letter or number).

Answer (score 0):

```
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    if(r.nextBoolean())
       A = r.nextInt(10); 
    else
       a = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'A');
```

Do you mean something like this?

If you want it in a function, have it return an integer and then interpret the result as either a letter or a number depending on the nextBoolen check outside.

Comment: Note that this gives each digit a higher probability than any particular letter.

Comment: @AndyThomas it gives a somewhat equal chance of it being a letter or a digit, as I understood it, that was the overall aim. You're right though in that, there being less numbers than letters, with a large enough number of picks there's gonna be a higher frequency of any specific number compared to any specific letter, but the overall amount of numbers vs letters should be equal.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm curious if it is possible to combine both and still receive on output(either letter or number).

Yes, it's possible.

One approach would be to fill a byte array `candidates[]` with the ASCII letters and single-byte integral values. Then use `Random.nextInt( candidates.length )` to compute an index into the array.

Alternatively, you could compute `Random.nextInt(36)`, use the resulting values for 0-9, and compute letters mostly as you are now for 10-35 (after offsetting to 0-25).

The latter avoids holding a very small array in memory -- but at the cost of adding a test and a branch.

Answer (score 0):

Just generate a random integer from 0-36 (range of A-Z + range of 0-9), then map to the according ascii value:

```
char a = (char) L1.nextInt(36); // A-Z + 0-9
a += a > 9 ? 'A' - 10 : '0';
```

Comment: This will always produce a char, (although sometimes that char will be a digit) while the question seems to indicate that the output should be an integer half the times. This will therefore require additional checks to see if the char can be turned into an int.

Comment: @Athamas Half of the times? I'd think it should be randomly spread between A-Z and 0-9. Anyway, it's pretty easy to change the first line to `int` and then `if (random > 9) char c = ... else int i = ...`.